# Flickity via webpack returning different result

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2, flickity

I am installing Flickity using npm: `npm i flickity`.
Flickity version is `2.2.0`

Then I call and use like this:

```
import Flickity from 'flickity'
const flickity = new Flickity(el, options)
console.log(flickity)
```

I have checked the function `Flickity` and realize that it is minified after building via webpack, and it seems to return the different result for `flickity` object. Therefore, it causes the action/methods on flickity object to behave differently. Please see the attached screenshot below for better illustration:

Development environment:

[image: This one is on development environment]

Minified via webpack:

[image: This one is minified via webpack]

Could anyone give suggestions on what is wrong in my situation to fix this issue?

Update: One important piece of information I haven't mentioned is that  flickity object is initialized inside a vue component. It might be the reason for this problem.

```
carousel.vue

import Flickity from 'flickity'
export default {
    data () {
        return { options } // options object
    }
    mounted () {
        this.instance = new Flickity(this.$el, this.options)
        console.log(this.instance)
    }
}
```

I am using vue `2.6.10`. The result `this.instance` is different on the two environments as I stated above. I still need help on this issue.

Comment: What version of Flickity are you using ? v2 ?

Comment: Ah yes, I am using version 2.2.0. I have updated info.

Answer (score 1):

The right syntax is:

```
import Flickity from 'flickity';
```

**EDIT:**
It seems to work correctly, take a look at my [snippet](http://stackblitz.com/edit/react-h1zmrf) (I've used a react template but also plain es6 should be fine)

Comment: It seems to work correctly, take a look at my snippet (used a react template but also plain es6 should be fine)
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-h1zmrf